# How do you ensure code coverage for files with no matching spec files in an Angular 7 app?

Tags: angular, istanbul, karma-coverage

This question has been asked before but all answers appear to be out of date and do not result in full code coverage **including coverage for files with no spec file**.

When I run the command `ng-test --code-coverage` my results show far fewer source code checked than reality, because it is skiping files with no matching spec file. I have tried to solve this in a few ways including creating an app.module.spec file and importing app.module into it and this increased the reported tested lines of code, but after adding a new component without tests to a deeply nested module the numbers did not change.

Here is my karma config:

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-mocha-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
      thresholds: {
        statements: 80,
        lines: 80,
        branches: 80,
        functions: 80
      }
    },
    mochaReporter: {
      maxLogLines: 4
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'mocha', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

here is my tests.ts file

```
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

declare const require: any;

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```

Here is my tsconfig.spec.json file:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up deciding to write a schematic that generates missing spec files with absolute basic test implementations - just enough to new up components and services. Now my code coverage report looks correct.

Answer (score 4):

I've just created karma plugin, which adds all the files in the project to coverage statistic - https://github.com/kopach/karma-sabarivka-reporter.

To use it -> install `npm install --save-dev karma-sabarivka-reporter`

And update `karma.conf.js` like this:

```
reporters: [
  // ...
  'sabarivka'
  // ...
],
coverageReporter: {
    include: 'src/**/!(*.spec|*.module|environment*).ts', // glob patter which  matchs all the files you want to be included into the coverage result
    exclude: 'src/main.ts',
    // ...
},
```

This should solve your issue without a need of creating "empty" spec files just to include source code file to the coverage report.